# Embedding youtube into flash with actionscript 3 using variables

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, flash

I have this code working ok, but I need to pass the video ID as a variable from php (which is taken from a db):

AS3 CODE:

```
package test_fla
{
import fl.controls.*;
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.system.*;

dynamic public class MainTimeline extends MovieClip
{
    public var pause_btn:Button;
    public var play_btn:Button;
    public var my_player:Object;
    public var my_loader:Loader;

    public function MainTimeline()
    {
        addFrameScript(0, this.frame1);
        this.__setProp_pause_btn_Scene1_Layer1_0();
        this.__setProp_play_btn_Scene1_Layer1_0();
        return;
    }// end function

    public function onLoaderInit(param1:Event) : void
    {
        addChild(this.my_loader);
        this.my_player = this.my_loader.content;
        this.my_player.addEventListener("onReady", this.onPlayerReady);
        return;
    }// end function

    public function onPlayerReady(param1:Event) : void
    {
        this.my_player.x = 30;
        this.my_player.setSize(640, 360);
        this.my_player.cueVideoById("xEPBcJtd11A", 0, "small");
        return;
    }// end function

    public function playVid(param1:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        this.my_player.playVideo();
        return;
    }// end function

    public function pauseVid(param1:MouseEvent) : void
    {
        this.my_player.pauseVideo();
        return;
    }// end function

    function __setProp_pause_btn_Scene1_Layer1_0()
    {
        try
        {
            this.pause_btn["componentInspectorSetting"] = true;
        }// end try
        catch (e:Error)
        {
        }// end catch
        this.pause_btn.emphasized = false;
        this.pause_btn.enabled = true;
        this.pause_btn.label = "Pausa";
        this.pause_btn.labelPlacement = "right";
        this.pause_btn.selected = false;
        this.pause_btn.toggle = false;
        this.pause_btn.visible = true;
        try
        {
            this.pause_btn["componentInspectorSetting"] = false;
        }// end try
        catch (e:Error)
        {
        }// end catch
        return;
    }// end function

    function __setProp_play_btn_Scene1_Layer1_0()
    {
        try
        {
            this.play_btn["componentInspectorSetting"] = true;
        }// end try
        catch (e:Error)
        {
        }// end catch
        this.play_btn.emphasized = false;
        this.play_btn.enabled = true;
        this.play_btn.label = "Play";
        this.play_btn.labelPlacement = "right";
        this.play_btn.selected = false;
        this.play_btn.toggle = false;
        this.play_btn.visible = true;
        try
        {
            this.play_btn["componentInspectorSetting"] = false;
        }// end try
        catch (e:Error)
        {
        }// end catch
        return;
    }// end function

    function frame1()
    {
        Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
        this.my_loader = new Loader();
        this.my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
        this.my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, this.onLoaderInit);
        this.play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.playVid);
        this.pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.pauseVid);
        return;
    }// end function

}
```

}

So, how would you do the same but passing a php variable as the video id instead of this.my_player.cueVideoById("**xEPBcJtd11A**", 0, "small"); directly?

thanks !!!

Comment: There are a whole load of questions on this site already detailing the answer on how to pass variables from PHP to AS3.

Comment: yes, but I don't work with as3 and I don't get it... this is just a customer need and I can't find the way...